# How can I determine if day, month, or year values are present in a non standardized set of date strings in PHP?

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I have a set of unstandardized date strings and I am trying to determine whether or not day, month, or year values are present in them. Some dates in the set have day, month, and year while others may have only year or just the year and month.

Examples:
`date('Y-m-d', strtotime('April 1982'))`
Returns: 1982-04-01
Desired result: 1982-04-00

`date('Y-m-d', strtotime('1982'))`
Returns: 1982-08-11 (month & day being current date)
Desired result: 1982-00-00

Edit:
Forget the desired results as I no longer plan on representing them by 00s. I'm just trying to determine whether day, month, or year values are present in a string as the title suggests.

Comment: You're going to have to write something. The `date()` function is not designed to work as you are asking.

Comment: 1982-00-00 is not a valid date, you expect a date function to return an invalid date?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Goal is use these to populate a MySQL field and MySQL does accept this format as part of their DATE type. Surely strtotime would have already some logic in it that determines whether or not a day or month is present in a string so I'm surprised PHP has no function for this.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Thanks.

Comment: The reason there is no such function to interpret a date is because people write dates in all kinds of ways. And some is ambiguous. If I gave you a date like 10-11-12. What year was I thinking of. It's impossible. And I strongly advice against adding invalid dates in a table. When you want to use them in the future you will have to go through all this mess again.

Comment: @Andreas Noted. In a situation where month and day are some sometimes unavailable, it seems best approach is to have a separate field for each date value.

Comment: How about reverse checking. If you have got `April 1982` and `1982-04-01` then verify if 1982 is presented in first string - yes it is - we have got year, then check if 04 or April is presented in string - yes, it is - we have got month too. Lets check the latest value `01` - that one is missing - we don't have the day. Edge cases are like 19 - additional logic have to be implemented to verify if is it part of the day or is it part of year

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski This is a decent approach, but will need to account for the all the edge cases like you said. 04 could be found in 2004. I'm working with formats like 'April 22nd, 2011' as well.

Answer (score 0):

The [date_parse()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.date-parse.php) function is suitable for this problem. However, it has a bug in my opinion. If not exist a day the day is also shown as 1. See User Contributed Notes [date_parse()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.date-parse.php).

The following function DateAnalysis tries to eliminate this with a regular expression:

```
function DateAnalysis($dateString){
  $components = date_parse($dateString);
  if($components['day'] === 1 AND 
    preg_match('~^1 |^01 |\-01$|\-1$~',$dateString) == 0){
    $components['day'] = false;
  }
  return $components;
}
```

Further variants can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27052374/php-date-parsefeb-2010-gives-day-1).

example:

```
var_dump(DateAnalysis('April 1986'));
```

output:

```
array(12) {
  ["year"]=>
  int(1986)
  ["month"]=>
  int(4)
  ["day"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["hour"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["minute"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["second"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["fraction"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["warning_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["warnings"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["error_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["errors"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["is_localtime"]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

I don't know all possible variations of how days can appear in the date string. The regular expression must be expanded as required.

Comment: Thanks. This points me in the right direction. Your example fails under date formats with 01 as the day such as 'April 01, 1987' and and instances where only the year is given, but the functions in the link you provided seem to work for my needs.